# unable to connect SSID from scan result - Android

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager, ssid

I have used WifiManager to scan the available wifi using,

```
mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        mainWifi.startScan();
```

I can get list of networks.

but when I try to connect to Speecific wifi SSID  `String hotspot="some_wifi_name";` in this case, It add the hotspot to WifiConfig but after that it goes in Infinite loop while connecting and again scans the result, an loop goes on.

Following is `Broadcast Receiver` I used for connecting thi my SSID,

```
class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    ArrayList<String> connections = new ArrayList<String>();
    WifiConfiguration conf;

    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) c
                .getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        List<ScanResult> wifiList;
        wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
        for (int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++) {

            String ssid = wifiList.get(i).SSID;
            int rssi = wifiList.get(i).level;
            Log.d("SSID: ", "" + wifiList.get(i).SSID.toString()
                    + " signal: " + rssi);

            if (ssid != null && ssid.equals(hotspot)) {
                Log.d("SSID Hotspot: ",
                        "" + wifiList.get(i).SSID.toString());
                conf = new WifiConfiguration();
                conf.SSID = "\"" + hotspot + "\"";
                conf.allowedKeyManagement
                        .set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
                wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);
            }
        }

        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();

        loops:
        for (WifiConfiguration j : list) {


            if (j.SSID != null && j.SSID.equals("\"" + hotspot + "\"")) {
                Log.d("Config", "" + j.SSID);
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(j.networkId, true);

                wifiManager.reconnect();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why It is scanning the wifi again after getting desired SSID and goes in the Infinite Loop, where is the wrong thing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding A SSID to configuration list I Unregistered the `BroadcastReceiver` .

so after next scan that function will not get executed.

Answer (score 1):

This code should let you connect to a concrete SSID:

```
public void connectToWifi(String ssid) {

    WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
    conf.SSID = "\"" + ssid + "\""; // Please note the quotes.
                                                // String should contain
                                                // ssid in quotes

    conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

    wifiMgr.addNetwork(conf);
    Log.d(TAG, ssid+" added");

    List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiMgr.getConfiguredNetworks();
    for (WifiConfiguration i : list) {
        if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals("\"" + ssid + "\"")) {
            wifiMgr.disconnect();
            wifiMgr.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true);
            wifiMgr.reconnect();
            Log.d(PluginConstants.LOG_TAG, "conneting to: ssid");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After adding that SSID to WifiConfig and Enabling it, wifi network scan again starts and receiver of WifiReceiver again gets executed. that's why Infinite Loop was occurring. same Problem persist with this code also. I think I need to stop scan After adding SSID to configured Network

Comment: This code is Simplified form, Thanks for it :) . I solved My problem by unregistering BrodcastReceiver after adding SSID to Configuration List